# Access to Grandeur Cloud has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cloud, iot, esp8266, serverless

I am working on building an Internet Switch with Grandeur Cloud and following the tutorial on [hackster](https://www.hackster.io/grandeur/internet-switch-with-grandeur-cloud-0a4f66). I am running the example provided but it is giving me `Blocked by CORS policy` error. The code snipped is attached as below

```
/*
    @file: main.js
    Initialize the SDK and get
    a reference to the project
*/

var apolloProject = apollo.init("YOUR-API-KEY", "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY", "YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN");

/*
    Function to login user
    we creating while getting started
*/
async function login() {
    /* Store credentials into variables */
    var email = "EMAIL";
    var password = "PASSWORD";

    /* Set the status to logging in */
    document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Logging in";

    /* Then get a reference to auth class */
    var auth = apolloProject.auth();

    /* and in a try catch block */
    try {
        /* Submit request using login function */
        var res = await auth.login(email, password);

        /* 
            Got the response to login
            handle response
        */
        switch(res.code) {
            case "AUTH-ACCOUNT-LOGGEDIN": 
            case "AUTH-ACCOUNT-ALREADY-LOGGEDIN":
                /*
                    User Authenticated
                    Set the status to success
                */
                document.getElementById("status").innerText = "User Authenticated";
                break;

            default: 
                /* 
                    Logging failed due
                    to invalid data
                */
                document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Authentication Failed";
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        /*
            Error usually got generated when
            we are not connected to the internet
        */
        document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Network Error";
    }
}

/* Call login on startup */
login();
```

What I am possibly doing wrong?

[image: The screenshot of error]

Note: I have reviewed the suggestions given, but it is not about the generic CORS error. It is a platform specific question. Grandeur Cloud is a BaaS platform for IoT and I am using it as backend for my app and hardware. So you can whitelist the allowed domain but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I reviewed your suggestion and comment, but it is not about the CORS error in general. I am using Grandeur Cloud which a BaaS platform for IoT. I am using it as backend for my app and hardware. They allow you to whitelist allowed domain but I don't know how to configure it. Can you please reopen the question?

Comment: You need to not run on localhost but on an allowed domain

Comment: But in the tagged tutorial, the writer has tested the app on localhost. It is possible I guess, you are just required to configure some settings (which I clearly don't know how to).

Comment: [RTM](https://github.com/grandeurtech/grandeurcloud-js-sdk#authentication-and-access) 
_In the end, it is important to note it comes with CORS protection in it by default. So to start communicating with the cloud platform, simply visit [settings page](https://cloud.grandeur.tech/settings) at cloud dashboard and whitelist the domain that your web app is using (if you are testing it locally and haven't deployed it to a domain yet, just add localhost:[port] to the allowed domains list but don't forget to remove it from a list before shipping you app in production)._

Comment: Thanks for helping. I should have looked at the docs more carefully.

Comment: Feel free to delete this

Comment: What about leaving it? Like others can get into same error? As you have probably noticed that it's not well documented ATM. What would you suggest?

Comment: It is VERY well documented  - you just had to scroll down 2 more paragraphs further than the video you looked at, but by all means.

Comment: This is a Javascript issue and has nothing to do with the ESP8266.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the resources that you tagged. Probably you are missing a step. You are required to add the localhost or the domain from which you are sending the request to whitelist. Here is how you can do it (ref. [getting started tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/grandeur/hello-world-with-grandeur-cloud-48e065#toc-step-6--test-the-app-locally-5))

1. Go to [settings](https://cloud.grandeur.tech/settings) page
2. From the `Project details` section, click on the `Update Allowed Domains`
3. Add the domain (with http or https prefixed) and press enter
4. Then click on update button and you will be able to send request

I would encourage you to go through the [docs](https://github.com/grandeurtech/grandeurcloud-js-sdk) for more info.